# Can't understand why my Javascript functions don't work?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to use some simple Javascript functions to change an `<img>`'s source to another picture when a button is pressed.

However, none of the buttons seem to work, not even the last one I made just to test whether I would get an alert.

I have tried figuring out what's wrong but I can't seem to find it. I have already searched similar questions and threads but the solution never applied to my case...

Thank you. (I only posted the `<body></body>` tags because there's nothing special in the `<head>` and co. tags)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunctionMice() {
        document.getElementById("target").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png">;
    };

    function myFunctionLaser() {
        document.getElementById("target").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png" >;
    };

    function myFunctionBirds() {
        document.getElementById("target").src = "http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/47/47080.png">;
    };

    function myTry() {
        alert("example");
    };

</script>    

<h1 align="center">Web4Cats</h1>

<nav>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionBirds()">Birds</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionMice()">Mice</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionLaser()">Laser</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myTry()">Try</button>
</nav>

<img id="target" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png">
```

Comment: There's a syntax error - remove all the `>` at the end of the lines where you set the new source.

Comment: Indeed. you should also be getting errors in your console - don't ignore those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. This `>;` needs to be removed. Otherwise your src is not valid. Look at the snippet below to see that your approach was good.

```js
    function myFunctionMice() {
        document.getElementById("target").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png"
    };

    function myFunctionLaser() {
        document.getElementById("target").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png" 
    };

    function myFunctionBirds() {
        document.getElementById("target").src = "http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/47/47080.png"
    };

    function myTry() {
        alert("example");
    };
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Web4Cats</h1>

<nav>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionBirds()">Birds</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionMice()">Mice</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionLaser()">Laser</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myTry()">Try</button>
</nav>

<img id="target" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

the issues are 1.'>' must be removed after image url
               2.your javascript code must be declared after the html code

```
            <h1 align="center">Web4Cats</h1>

            <nav>
                <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionBirds()">Birds</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionMice()">Mice</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionLaser()">Laser</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="myTry()">Try</button>
            </nav>
            <img id="target" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png">

<script>
        function myFunctionMice() {
               document.getElementById("target").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png"
};
        function myFunctionLaser() {
               document.getElementById("target").src = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/Z/f/0/p/W/mouse-with-smaller-ears-md.png" 
};
        function myFunctionBirds() {
               document.getElementById("target").src = "http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/47/47080.png"
};
        function myTry() {
               alert("example");
         };  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your '>' characters cause an error at the end of your src definitions in your javascript functions.
ex :

```
 document.getElementById("target").src = "http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/47/47080.png" **>** ;
```

should be :

```
document.getElementById("target").src = "http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/47/47080.png";
```

Do the same with every function in your code. it definitely works